# What is the Pacman lemma?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I've seen "the Pacman lemma" mentioned in the context of reduction orderings on logical terms, but a Google search doesn't find a definition; what exactly is it? Closest a search found was a "Pacman rule" in the context of calculus; is that the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Lemma.** : Let $(X,\mathcal{S})$   be a *measurable* space, $\nu$ a signed measure. Suppose we have a subset $E \in \mathcal{S}$ and $0 < \nu(E) < \infty$ . Then, there exists a positive set $P \subset E$  such that $\nu(P) > 0$.

I found it here:

- http://www.math.unl.edu/~s-bbockel1/921-notes/Signed_Measures.html

Comment: Why is this called the Pacman lemma? (For every E of positive measure there exists a positive set that "eats" it?(??))

Comment: Who knows? I had never heard of it, until i searched in **Google** :)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I guess it's in the proof. Eat all the really big negative subsets (nuggets) and whatever remains, as improbable as it seems, must be positive. Elementary, dear Watson!